# What is the role of this macro in function declaration?

Tags: c, function-declaration

I have downloaded some library and it declares the functions the following way:

```
#if !defined(__ANSI_PROTO)
#if defined(_WIN32) || defined(__STDC__) || defined(__cplusplus)
#  define __ANSI_PROTO(x)       x
#else
#  define __ANSI_PROTO(x)       ()
#endif
#endif

int httpdAddVariable __ANSI_PROTO((httpd*,char*, char*));
```

What is the role of `__ANSI_PROTO` here? Why it is preferred to declaring simply as

```
int httpdAddVariable (httpd*,char*, char*);
```

Comment: it a macros for declaring functions and arguments with or without 
 * ANSI C prototypes

Comment: Perhaps to cope with early C compilers which lacks argument signature?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pre-ANSI C didn't support this:

```
int httpdAddVariable (httpd*,char*, char*);
```

It only supported this:

```
int httpdAddVariable (); /* = arguments unspecified*/
```

So that's what the macro does. It pastes the argument types into the declaration if it detects prototype support; otherwise, it just pastes `()`.

Comment: So I can safely remove all appearances of this macro from the code?

Comment: Yes. (Unless you plan on supporting ancient compilers).